Issue on setup ci cd pipeline for mutiple folder in github action
In my Github repo under app folder their are multiple sub-folders like folder1, folder2 and folder3 I am able to create a workflow.yaml if any changes comes in folder1 it triggers ci/cd job for folder1 only, how can I achieve this for folder2 and folder3 also in the same workflow.yaml.
name: Build and Deploy folder1 App to Cloud Run development environment

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    paths:
      - 'app/folder1/**'

jobs:
  build-devops:
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write
      pull-requests: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - id: checkout
        name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # Authenticate to Google Cloud using Workload Identity Federation
      - id: gcp-auth
        name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: 'projects/4287/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/dev/providers/dev'
          service_account: 'data@dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
          access_token_lifetime: '3600s'

      # Set up Google Cloud SDK
      - name: Set up Google Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v2
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}  # Direct value instead of secret
          export_default_credentials: true
          

      # Configure Docker for Artifact Registry
      - name: Configure Docker for Artifact Registry
        run: gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west-docker.pkg.dev

      # Build Docker image for Cloud Run
      - name: Build Docker Image
        run: |
          docker build -t ${{ secrets.GCP_REGION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/gcf-artifacts/folder1 ./app/folder1

      # Push Docker image to Google Cloud Artifact Registry
      - name: Push Docker Image to Artifact Registry
        run: |
          docker push ${{ secrets.GCP_REGION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/gcf-artifacts/folder1

Note :- I want to set condition that if any changes happens for any of this folder it should trigger job respective to that folder only for e.g if any changes happen on folder2 it should trigger job related to folder2 only.

The paths-filter action is pretty great for this kind of "what has changed?" functionality.

Here's how you can modify your workflow file to achieve this:
name: Build and Deploy App to Cloud Run development environment

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    paths:
      - 'app/folder1/**'
      - 'app/folder2/**'
      - 'app/folder3/**'

jobs:
  build-devops:
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write
      pull-requests: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        folder: [folder1, folder2, folder3]

    steps:
      - id: check-folder
        name: Check if folder changed
        run: |
          git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | grep -q "^app/${{ matrix.folder }}/"
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Skip if no changes
        if: ${{ failure() }}
        run: echo "No changes detected in ${{ matrix.folder }}. Skipping job."

      - name: Checkout repository
        if: ${{ success() }}
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - id: gcp-auth
        name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
        if: ${{ success() }}
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: 'projects/4287/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/dev/providers/dev'
          service_account: 'data@dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
          access_token_lifetime: '3600s'

      - name: Set up Google Cloud SDK
        if: ${{ success() }}
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v2
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
          export_default_credentials: true

      - name: Configure Docker for Artifact Registry
        if: ${{ success() }}
        run: gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west-docker.pkg.dev

      - name: Build Docker Image
        if: ${{ success() }}
        run: |
          docker build -t ${{ secrets.GCP_REGION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/gcf-artifacts/${{ matrix.folder }} ./app/${{ matrix.folder }}

      - name: Push Docker Image to Artifact Registry
        if: ${{ success() }}
        run: |
          docker push ${{ secrets.GCP_REGION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/gcf-artifacts/${{ matrix.folder }}


I tried this yaml as per the suggestion but the problem is even though I do some changes in folder1 only it is also triggering for folder2, so at the same time 2 jobs are getting triggered which I dont want.
